# iframe doesn't readjust for mobile vertical view

Tags: css, html, iframe, responsive-design

I am still an HTML5 rookie and so far I got something up that's pretty snazzy. I found a template over on HTML5UP which I have been tinkering with, changing the CSS and taking out parts I didn't need, as well as added a couple of things myself.

Now, I wanted to show some images in a gallery, which I have achieved. It works pretty good on mobile too. The other thing I wanted to show, was my YouTube channels playlist, embedded using `iframe`. On the desktop it looks just fine, but on mobile it breaks the site when viewing the page vertically. I would like to know if there is a way to force the iframe to resize because of a phone screen or if I have to maybe go in another direction with this? (Like using the Video and Audio libraries in JavaScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can give your code that would be helpful, however I believe [this](http://codepen.io/gvenech/full/rzJow/) is what you are trying to achieve?

Just give your iframe width a percentage instead of a pixel number. However I recommend you change the height as well, as you can see it looks funny at certain widths.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ep7W89I_V_g" frameborder="0"      allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I also suggest you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)  on media queries.

Comment: I figured it out in the meantime. I used some CSS trickery to make it work. Basically you wrap the iframe in a class container and then use CSS to impose aspect ratios on the container. Then you just have to make sure that the container your new video wrapper is in, is responsive (by telling it that width: 100%;)

Comment: I'll choose your answer though, as it is a solution too. Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Gracias, tryna get those 50 points at least so I can comment anywhere haha